# Does an Arduino 101 come with bluetooth HID capabilities?

Tags: bluetooth

I would like to prototype an Ergodox-like keyboard. My take on this good design would be to affix each half of the keyboard to my chair's armrests, so that the arms are always in a natural relaxed position. In order to achieve this, bluetooth capabilities seem necessary in order to avoid cable mayhem each time I move the chair.

I am aware that the Arduino Leonardo has USB-HID capabilities, but will that translate to the additional USB module that would be required? I saw that Adafruit has an EZ-key bluetooth module that seems to fit the bill, but even so, it would require more cabling and complexity, for a project that is already very near my threshold (or above it).

What would be easy is if the Arduino 101 had HID capabilities. I would just need to solder the matrix of keys, and almost be done. Does it?

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 2):

The Arduino 101 has HID capabilities. I found example code for using the Arduino 101 as a keyboard, as well as some other discussions saying that the Arduino 101 has HID capabilities.

[Here is some example code on GitHub](https://github.com/mo10/Curie-bluetooth-HID-library/tree/master/src).